# Compact set A in R^2

Tags: real-analysis

Hey guys I need help considering the following problem:

Say we have a set $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $A$ is compact. Show that there is a point in $A$ which has $y$ coordinate at least as large as the $y$ coordinate of any other point in $A$. (Hint: Use the the sup norm of $A$).

Here is my attempt:

$A$ is compact -> $A$ is closed and bounded. Say there exist $x_n$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and $y_n$ in $\mathbb{R}$ s.t.

$x_n \to x_0 = \sup(x_n)$ and $y_n \to y_0 = \sup(y_n)$ as $n \to \infty$ such that

$$\|(x,y)\| < \|(x_0,y_0)\|.$$

Now from the definition of the limits of $x_n$ and $y_n$ there exist the integers $N_1$ and $N_2$ and the real value $e > 0$ such that $|x_n-x_0|<e$ whenever $n > N_1$ and $|y_n-y_0|<e$ whenever $n > N_2$.

Can I use the fact that either $N_1 > N_2$ or $N_1 < N_2$ or $N_1 = N_2$ holds such that I know which sequence converges first to prove the problem statement?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Edit: Now from the definition of the limits of x_n and y_n there exist the integers N_1 and N_2 and the real value e > 0 such that |x_n-x_0| whenever n> N_1 and |y_n-y_0| whenever n> N_2.

Comment: An easy way to do this is to observe i) the function $f(x,y)=y$ is continuous on $A$ and ii) every continuous real valued function on a compact set attains a maximum value.

Comment: The solution proposed in the question won't work since none of the quantities equals the sup of all y coordinates of points in A.  You need to choose the sequence such that that happens.  For example, if M is the sup of the y coordinates, choose the nth point so that $y_n > M - \frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_0=\sup \{x:\exists (x,y)\in A\}$ and $y_0=\sup \{y:\exists (x,y)\in A\}.$

It may be that $(x_0,y_0)\not \in A$ even for  compact $A.$ For example let $A=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=1\}.$ Then $(x_0,y_0)=(1,1)\not \in A.$

Let $((x_n,y_n))_{n\in \Bbb N}$ be a sequence of points of $A$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}y_n=y_0.$  Since $(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ is a bounded sequence in $\Bbb R$ (because $A$ is bounded), it has a convergent sub-sequence.

So let $f:\Bbb N\to \Bbb N$ be strictly increasing such that the limit $x=\lim_{n\to \infty}x_{f(n)}$ exists.. Then $((x_{f(n)},y_{f(n)}))_{n\in \Bbb N}$ is a sequence in $A$ converging to $(x,y_0).$ Since $A$ is closed we have $(x,y_0)\in A. $